# How to create and run Apache JMeter Test Scripts from a Java program?

Tags: java, api, automated-tests, jmeter

I want to use the API provided by Apache JMeter to create and run test scripts from a Java program. I have understood the basics of ThreadGroup and Samplers. I can create those in my Java class by using the JMeter API.

```
ThreadGroup threadGroup = new ThreadGroup();
    LoopController lc = new LoopController();
    lc.setLoops(5);
    lc.setContinueForever(true);
    threadGroup.setSamplerController(lc);
    threadGroup.setNumThreads(5);
    threadGroup.setRampUp(1);

HTTPSampler sampler = new HTTPSampler();
    sampler.setDomain("localhost");
    sampler.setPort(8080);
    sampler.setPath("/jpetstore/shop/viewCategory.shtml");
    sampler.setMethod("GET");

    Arguments arg = new Arguments();
    arg.addArgument("categoryId", "FISH");

    sampler.setArguments(arg);
```

However, I am not getting any idea on how to create a test script combining the thread group and sampler and then execute it from the same program. Any ideas?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to run an entire test plan programmatically from within a Java program. Personally, I find it easier to create a test plan .JMX file and run it in JMeter non-GUI mode :)

Here is a simple Java example based on the controller and sampler used in the original question.

```
import org.apache.jmeter.control.LoopController;
import org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine;
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSampler;
import org.apache.jmeter.testelement.TestElement;
import org.apache.jmeter.testelement.TestPlan;
import org.apache.jmeter.threads.SetupThreadGroup;
import org.apache.jmeter.util.JMeterUtils;
import org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree;

public class JMeterTestFromCode {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        // Engine
        StandardJMeterEngine jm = new StandardJMeterEngine();
        // jmeter.properties
        JMeterUtils.loadJMeterProperties("c:/tmp/jmeter.properties");

        HashTree hashTree = new HashTree();     

        // HTTP Sampler
        HTTPSampler httpSampler = new HTTPSampler();
        httpSampler.setDomain("www.google.com");
        httpSampler.setPort(80);
        httpSampler.setPath("/");
        httpSampler.setMethod("GET");

        // Loop Controller
        TestElement loopCtrl = new LoopController();
        ((LoopController)loopCtrl).setLoops(1);
        ((LoopController)loopCtrl).addTestElement(httpSampler);
        ((LoopController)loopCtrl).setFirst(true);

        // Thread Group
        SetupThreadGroup threadGroup = new SetupThreadGroup();
        threadGroup.setNumThreads(1);
        threadGroup.setRampUp(1);
        threadGroup.setSamplerController((LoopController)loopCtrl);

        // Test plan
        TestPlan testPlan = new TestPlan("MY TEST PLAN");

        hashTree.add("testPlan", testPlan);
        hashTree.add("loopCtrl", loopCtrl);
        hashTree.add("threadGroup", threadGroup);
        hashTree.add("httpSampler", httpSampler);       

        jm.configure(hashTree);

        jm.run();
    }
}
```

**Dependencies**

These are the bare mininum JARs required based on JMeter 2.9 and the HTTPSampler used.
Other samplers will most likely have different library JAR dependencies.

- ApacheJMeter_core.jar
- jorphan.jar
- avalon-framework-4.1.4.jar
- ApacheJMeter_http.jar
- commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
- logkit-2.0.jar
- oro-2.0.8.jar
- commons-io-2.2.jar
- commons-lang3-3.1.jar

**Note**

- I also hardwired the path to jmeter.properties in c:\tmp on Windows after first copying it  from the JMeter installation /bin directory.
- I wasn't sure how to set a forward proxy for the HTTPSampler.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is exactly what I was looking for. Just one more thing. I think adding the LoopController to the ThreadGroup is enough. Adding it separately to the HashTree is not necessary.

Comment: Good point on the additions to the HashTree. I was playing around with the JMeter API a little while back but I'm a bit rusty on the details of data structure passed into the JMeter Engine configure method :)

Comment: Hi.I am getting the following error. 2014-02-16 18:22:20.957 [jorphan.] (): strPathsOrJars[0] : null/lib/ext
DEBUG   2014-02-16 18:22:20.957 [jorphan.] (): Did not find: C:/Users/mvandrangi/workspace/mani/bin
DEBUG   2014-02-16 18:22:20.957 [jorphan.] (): Did not find: C:/Users/mvandrangi/Downloads/apache-jmeter-2.11/bin/ApacheJMeter.jar
DEBUG   2014-02-16 18:22:20.957 [jorphan.] (): Did not find: C:/Users/mvandrangi/Downloads/apache-jmeter-2.11/bin/ApacheJMeter_core.jar

Comment: Interesting. I get the same jorphan DEBUG messages but the program is executing the test plan correctly. I believe that JOrphan is trying to locate those jar files in the JDK/jre/lib/ext directory.

Comment: @Peperoncini will the code automatically generate jmx file or should we have to have a jmx file?

Comment: [jmeter.e](): About to replace in property of type:class org.apache.jmeter.testelement.property.BooleanProperty:false                  I am getting these errors

Comment: @manideepak - This particular sample does not use a .JMX file at all. The OP desired a means to create and run a JMeter test case using Java code only. Running this after first compiling it will generate a lot of logging output messages, and I would be more concerned about the actual ERROR messages as opposed to the DEBUG and INFO messages. Are you able to run the above Java code in your environment?

Comment: @Peperoncini  We are getting no error messages but                             [jorphan.] ():searchPathsOrJars : [null/lib/ext] and also StrPathOfJars: null/lib/ext although we have set the path of JMETER_HOME

Comment: I am not positive that the JMETER_HOME environment variable will be sufficient to find all of the required JAR files, since it generally points to the top directory of the JMeter installation.

Have you tried setting CLASSPATH to include all of the JARs listed under "Dependencies" in this post? When I created this code snippet, I had the Java source and all of the above mentioned JAR files in the same working directory (copied from the JMeter installation directory).

Comment: [Here is the list of files. r.cmd and c.cmd are shown in next comment. FYI: I'm running on Windows XP using JDK 6] -- ApacheJMeter_core.jar
ApacheJMeter_http.jar avalon-framework-4.1.4.jar c.cmd
commons-io-2.2.jar commons-lang3-3.1.jar commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
JMeterTestFromCode.class JMeterTestFromCode.java jorphan.jar
logkit-2.0.jar oro-2.0.8.jar r.cmd

Comment: [Contents of the compilation batch script "c.cmd"] -- javac -cp .;ApacheJmeter_core.jar;commons-io-2.2.jar;commons-lang3-3.1.jar;jorphan.jar;commons-logging-1.1.1.jar;logkit-2.0.jar;oro-2.0.8.jar;avalon-framework-4.1.4.jar;ApacheJmeter_http.jar JMeterTestFromCode.java

Comment: [Contents of the execution batch script "r.cmd"] -- java -cp .;ApacheJmeter_core.jar;commons-io-2.2.jar;commons-lang3-3.1.jar;jorphan.jar;commons-logging-1.1.1.jar;logkit-2.0.jar;oro-2.0.8.jar;avalon-framework-4.1.4.jar;ApacheJmeter_http.jar JMeterTestFromCode

Comment: @Peperoncini Yes. I included all my jar files but we are getting the above messages. I tried in eclipse.I set the path in jmeter.properties file also. Had u tried in an IDE or from scratch?Can u share ur project with me?

Comment: @manideepak I was not using an IDE. Everything was compiled and run from the DOS Prompt on Windows XP using JDK 6. Everything I used is here in this post and comments. Hope that helps.

Comment: @Peperoncini I tried all the jars mentioned previously and still got the debub messages as "Wont replace 3"(setNumThreads) in jm.run()

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48546/discussion-between-peperoncini-and-mani-deepak)

Comment: @JTP, thanx a lot for the code, but how can i run this if i want to run Distributed Testing?

Comment: @VishalPuliani I'm not sure if it is even possible or practical to use the standalone Java program for distributed testing.

Comment: I copy-pasted this example to my maven project, in which I have dependencies for ApacheJMeter_core and ApacheJMeter_http. What happens to me is that the sampler is never called. I investigated why and it seems that the hash tree being cloned into the JMeterThread is cloned absent the LoopController. So at this part: `Sampler e = this.threadGroupLoopController.next();

                while(true) {
                    while(this.running && e != null) {` it does not execute the loop and the sampler is not called. What gives?

Comment: How to specify log file? I ran without any exception but also no results/log.

Comment: @Nom1fan were you able to resolve the issue that you mentioned? I am facing the same error currently, and not sure how to fix this.

Comment: @PratyakshSharma many years have passsed so I honestly don't remember. I also can't check since I don't work in eBay anymore where I faced this. IIRC I made some code changes and didn't use this example as-is, but like I said I really don't recall what they were exactly.

Answer (score 14):

```
package jMeter;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.jmeter.config.Arguments;
import org.apache.jmeter.config.gui.ArgumentsPanel;
import org.apache.jmeter.control.LoopController;
import org.apache.jmeter.control.gui.LoopControlPanel;
import org.apache.jmeter.control.gui.TestPlanGui;
import org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine;
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.gui.HttpTestSampleGui;
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy;
import org.apache.jmeter.reporters.ResultCollector;
import org.apache.jmeter.reporters.Summariser;
import org.apache.jmeter.save.SaveService;
import org.apache.jmeter.testelement.TestElement;
import org.apache.jmeter.testelement.TestPlan;
import org.apache.jmeter.threads.ThreadGroup;
import org.apache.jmeter.threads.gui.ThreadGroupGui;
import org.apache.jmeter.util.JMeterUtils;
import org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree;

public class JMeterFromScratch {

        public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {

            String jmeterHome1 = "/home/ksahu/apache-jmeter-2.13";
            File jmeterHome=new File(jmeterHome1);
//          JMeterUtils.setJMeterHome(jmeterHome);
            String slash = System.getProperty("file.separator");

            if (jmeterHome.exists()) {
                File jmeterProperties = new File(jmeterHome.getPath() + slash + "bin" + slash + "jmeter.properties");
                if (jmeterProperties.exists()) {
                    //JMeter Engine
                    StandardJMeterEngine jmeter = new StandardJMeterEngine();

                    //JMeter initialization (properties, log levels, locale, etc)
                    JMeterUtils.setJMeterHome(jmeterHome.getPath());
                    JMeterUtils.loadJMeterProperties(jmeterProperties.getPath());
                    JMeterUtils.initLogging();// you can comment this line out to see extra log messages of i.e. DEBUG level
                    JMeterUtils.initLocale();

                    // JMeter Test Plan, basically JOrphan HashTree
                    HashTree testPlanTree = new HashTree();

                    // First HTTP Sampler - open example.com
                    HTTPSamplerProxy examplecomSampler = new HTTPSamplerProxy();
                    examplecomSampler.setDomain("www.google.com");
                    examplecomSampler.setPort(80);
                    examplecomSampler.setPath("/");
                    examplecomSampler.setMethod("GET");
                    examplecomSampler.setName("Open example.com");
                    examplecomSampler.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, HTTPSamplerProxy.class.getName());
                    examplecomSampler.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, HttpTestSampleGui.class.getName());


                    // Second HTTP Sampler - open blazemeter.com
                    HTTPSamplerProxy blazemetercomSampler = new HTTPSamplerProxy();
                    blazemetercomSampler.setDomain("www.tripodtech.net");
                    blazemetercomSampler.setPort(80);
                    blazemetercomSampler.setPath("/");
                    blazemetercomSampler.setMethod("GET");
                    blazemetercomSampler.setName("Open blazemeter.com");
                    blazemetercomSampler.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, HTTPSamplerProxy.class.getName());
                    blazemetercomSampler.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, HttpTestSampleGui.class.getName());


                    // Loop Controller
                    LoopController loopController = new LoopController();
                    loopController.setLoops(1);
                    loopController.setFirst(true);
                    loopController.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, LoopController.class.getName());
                    loopController.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, LoopControlPanel.class.getName());
                    loopController.initialize();

                    // Thread Group
                    ThreadGroup threadGroup = new ThreadGroup();
                    threadGroup.setName("Example Thread Group");
                    threadGroup.setNumThreads(1);
                    threadGroup.setRampUp(1);
                    threadGroup.setSamplerController(loopController);
                    threadGroup.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, ThreadGroup.class.getName());
                    threadGroup.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, ThreadGroupGui.class.getName());

                    // Test Plan
                    TestPlan testPlan = new TestPlan("Create JMeter Script From Java Code");
                    testPlan.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, TestPlan.class.getName());
                    testPlan.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, TestPlanGui.class.getName());
                    testPlan.setUserDefinedVariables((Arguments) new ArgumentsPanel().createTestElement());

                    // Construct Test Plan from previously initialized elements
                    testPlanTree.add(testPlan);
                    HashTree threadGroupHashTree = testPlanTree.add(testPlan, threadGroup);
                    threadGroupHashTree.add(blazemetercomSampler);
                    threadGroupHashTree.add(examplecomSampler);

                    // save generated test plan to JMeter's .jmx file format
                    SaveService.saveTree(testPlanTree, new FileOutputStream(jmeterHome + slash + "example.jmx"));

                    //add Summarizer output to get test progress in stdout like:
                    // summary =      2 in   1.3s =    1.5/s Avg:   631 Min:   290 Max:   973 Err:     0 (0.00%)
                    Summariser summer = null;
                    String summariserName = JMeterUtils.getPropDefault("summariser.name", "summary");
                    if (summariserName.length() > 0) {
                        summer = new Summariser(summariserName);
                    }


                    // Store execution results into a .jtl file
                    String logFile = jmeterHome + slash + "example.jtl";
                    ResultCollector logger = new ResultCollector(summer);
                    logger.setFilename(logFile);
                    testPlanTree.add(testPlanTree.getArray()[0], logger);

                    // Run Test Plan
                    jmeter.configure(testPlanTree);
                    jmeter.run();

                    System.out.println("Test completed. See " + jmeterHome + slash + "example.jtl file for results");
                    System.out.println("JMeter .jmx script is available at " + jmeterHome + slash + "example.jmx");
                    System.exit(0);

                }
            }

            System.err.println("jmeter.home property is not set or pointing to incorrect location");
            System.exit(1);


        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, what changes do i have to do when i want to run this as distributed testing?

Comment: Has anyone managed to generate html results, from the csv or jtl file, using java api?

Answer (score 7):

As of August 2020, you can try using this library :

- https://github.com/abstracta/jmeter-java-dsl

Using Maven, add to pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>us.abstracta.jmeter</groupId>
   <projectId>jmeter-java-dsl</projectId>
   <version>0.1</version>
 </dependency>
```

Sample code:

```
 import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;
 import static us.abstracta.jmeter.javadsl.JmeterDsl.*;

 import java.time.Duration;
 import org.eclipse.jetty.http.MimeTypes.Type;
 import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
 import us.abstracta.jmeter.javadsl.TestPlanStats;

 public class PerformanceTest {

   @Test
   public void testPerformance() throws IOException {
     TestPlanStats stats = testPlan(
        threadGroup(2, 10,
        httpSampler("http://my.service")
           .post("{\"name\": \"test\"}", Type.APPLICATION_JSON)
     ),
      //this is just to log details of each request stats
     jtlWriter("test.jtl")
     ).run();
              assertThat(stats.overall().elapsedTimePercentile99()).isLessThan(Duration.ofSeconds(5));
  }

 }
```

Answer (score 5):

I created a simple prove of concept project utilising JMeter Java Api
with Maven dependences:
https://github.com/piotrbo/jmeterpoc

You can either generate JMeter project jmx file and execute it from command line
or execute it directly from java code.

It was tricky a bit as jmx file requires existence of 'guiclass' attribute
for every TestElement.
To execute jmx, it is enough to add `guiclass` (even with incorrect value).
To open in JMeter GUI it requires to put correct value for each `guiclass`.

Much more annoying problem are condition based flow Controllers.
JMeter API does not gives you much more then GUI. You still need to pass
a `condition` e.g. in `IfController` as regular `String`. An the string should contain javascript. So you have Java based project with javascript with e.g. syntax error an you will not know it until you execute your performance test :-(

Probably a better alternative to stay with code and support of IDE instead JMeter GUI is to learn Scala a bit and use http://gatling.io/

Comment: It is not possible to open simpleProject_generated.jmx file with JMeter GUI!? it faced with error.

Answer (score 1):

Running in Non GUI mode is much more faster. Have made one project which is using Jmeter in backend mode and then parsing the XML file to display test results. Have a look at this repo- https://github.com/rohitjaryal/RESTApiAutomation.git