# Coding Using the classes of Jmeter

Tags: java, api, automated-tests, jmeter

I am using APIs of Jmeter to write a code which will run Jmeter.I am getting the following errors while using Jorphan, :

```
About to replace in property of type: class org.apache.jmeter.testelement.property.CollectionProperty: []
DEBUG   2014-02-17 09:37:36.942 [jmeter.e] (): Replacement result: []
DEBUG   2014-02-17 09:37:36.945 [jmeter.e] (): Replacement result: 
DEBUG   2014-02-17 09:37:36.945 [jmeter.e] (): About to replace in property of type: class org.apache.jmeter.testelement.property.StringProperty: www.google.com
```

Comment: **Check this answer** [How to create and run Apache JMeter Test Scripts from a Java program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19147235/how-to-create-and-run-apache-jmeter-test-scripts-from-a-java-program/) It may help you.

Comment: @Nitin:I had referred to the mentioned link earlier. It didn't work for me.