# Run Jmeter from code

Tags: java, automation, jmeter

I am tried to write a code to run Jmeter in java.I tried to google to find some resources but couldnot get much. Also tried to check stackoverflow and found some which are not helpful.so can someone please give any resources/code which will aid me.

Comment: Isn't it what you are looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19147235/how-to-create-and-run-apache-jmeter-test-scripts-from-a-java-program

Comment: @olyv But that is not working for me