# How to identify http response code without clicking on link

Tags: java, selenium

I want to get URL in LI tag through X PATH and Validate these URL based on its response code.

Could someone help me to get URL from below and to validate URL using response code.

```
<li class="menu-link divider">
<a onclick="getSearchOption('Amazon.com','http://www.amazon.com/s?url=');"></a>
</li
```

Comment: I would start by asking: The response code of what? I am pretty sure that there are more than 1 HTTP request been sent, each can have their own status code.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is not target for WebDriver and I'm also not sure that it should be done in the scope of UI automation but anyway let me suggest some solution. I would use JMeter API to check response codes. Here is some help [How to create and run Apache JMeter Test Scripts from a Java program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19147235/how-to-create-and-run-apache-jmeter-test-scripts-from-a-java-program) and here bit of JMeter API [getResponseCode()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html#getResponseCode%28%29)