# JMeter predefined JMX execution from java code

Tags: java, jdbc, jmeter, jmx

After searching for a long time I was not able to find a proper solution or documentation on how to run predefined JDBC JMeter Test Suites from java code. The tests have been defined in the JMX format.

I know that you can run it with the jmeter-n.cmd, but I need to execute the test from within my code.
Also, the Runtime.exec solution (as described in the link) is not feasable, as I cannot go out of my JVM.

[How to create and run Apache JMeter Test Scripts from a Java program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19147235/how-to-create-and-run-apache-jmeter-test-scripts-from-a-java-program)

Using the JMeter API or GUI, I was able to create some http and JDBC tests - but not run predefined ones.
Creating JDBC tests in the API did not work at all.
There is some basic documentation around, but I can only find solutions on how its done in the GUI.

Thanks and best regards

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [5 Ways To Launch a JMeter Test without Using the JMeter GUI](http://blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui) guide, it provides walkthrough on how to launch existing .jmx file from Java code and additionally clarifies how to build a JMeter test plan via API.