# Programming with JMeter API's

Tags: jmeter

I have worked with Jmeter for Perfromance testing. And had some hands on Experience with GUI.
Now Problem is Each and every time if i need to start performance testing , i need to load JMeter GUI and load my test plans [JMX] created and so..on..
So Now i am Planning to enhance my test Plans to next level as to make use of JMeter API's and write my own test plans and execute them..Which has to be Automated..

Can someone please suggest how to setup my IDE Environment [ANT , MAVEN , JAR's Required] for JMeter programming ? 
And is there any sample test program on web application trough Jmeter Java programming ?
please suggest if there are any links for sample programming jmeter test plans.

Comment: I see here three different questions: 1) how to tun JMeter in non-GUI mode, 2) how to integrate existent test plan with Ant or Maven, 3) how to use JMeter API. For the third one take a look at the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19147235/how-to-create-and-run-apache-jmeter-test-scripts-from-a-java-program/19236643#19236643 But do you really need it?

Comment: Thanks for the reply olyv. 
i need to setup an development environment and integrate existent test plan with Ant or Maven. By that i can write some new junit test cases and add it to my existing automation.
Please suggest if you have any ideas or share links which can help this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I think its better to use eclipse IDE with ant for Jmeter development. You can either build jmeter source code by ant command line or using Eclipse with ant. Refer the links provided which will help you to understand more about setup jmeter development environment. 1) [Jmeter-custom-build](http://code4reference.com/2013/06/jmeter-custom-build/)   or 2) [how-to-build-jmeter-from-sources-in-eclipse](http://artur.ejsmont.org/blog/content/how-to-build-jmeter-from-sources-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 0):

Last 2 chapters of the [5 Ways To Launch a JMeter Test without Using the JMeter GUI](http://blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui) guide demonstrate how to use JMeter's API to run existing test and to create a new test from scratch from Java code.

There is a [sample project on Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/blazemeter/jmeter-from-code/) which you should be able to use as a skeleton or reference.