# Running JMeter through Java

Tags: java, jmeter

I have `JMeter '.jmx'` file.

Can I run it using Java? If yes, please let me know how to do it or share any good link

Comment: I believe you can find your answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19147235/how-to-create-and-run-apache-jmeter-test-scripts-from-a-java-program

Comment: @cheseaux - i did try but could only found the link provided by style in the comment after you

Comment: @style - in that link, it is told how to create the requests and all. I already have the requests created in .jmx file. I only need to run that file

Comment: Are you kidding me ? First link I've found was the official documentation : https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#running, there is your answer.

Comment: @cheseaux: Nope, because apparently  he wants to run it from a Java program, not from the command line.

Comment: It would help if you better described what you are trying to do.  Since JMeter is a Java program, the short answer is yes and a pointer to the jmeter home page.  I assume that is not what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class [org.apache.jmeter.NewDriver](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/NewDriver.html) has the `main()` method that the application is started with. You can call it programmatically and pass it the appropriate arguments (like `-t test.jmx`). You probably have to [construct the test plan specifically](http://developer.amd.com/community/blog/2009/03/31/using-apache-jmeter-in-non-gui-mode/) to yield usable results if you want it to run without a GUI, though.

Comment: I am not able to get it working. Can you please provide me the code snippet regarding what needs to do to run test.jmx

Comment: Did you say that I do something like this NewDriver.main(), here I pass '-t test.jmx'?

Comment: @Anand: yes, though you may have to pass each part of the parameters separately (parameter type is String[])

Comment: I tried NewDriver.main(new String[]{"C:\\Users\\Anand.Jain\\Desktop\\hits.jmx"}); but it is giving me An error occurred: Unknown arg: C:\Users\Anand.Jain\Desktop\hits.jmx.

Comment: It is not looking in actual Jmeter directory and hence giving me these exceptions as well java.lang.Throwable: Could not access C:\workspace\learn\lib
 at org.apache.jmeter.NewDriver.<clinit>(NewDriver.java:99)
 at JmeterTest1.main(JmeterTest1.java:9)
java.lang.Throwable: Could not access C:\workspace\learn\lib\ext
 at org.apache.jmeter.NewDriver.<clinit>(NewDriver.java:99)
 at JmeterTest1.main(JmeterTest1.java:9)
java.lang.Throwable: Could not access C:\workspace\learn\lib\junit
 at org.apache.jmeter.NewDriver.<clinit>(NewDriver.java:99)
 at JmeterTest1.main(JmeterTest1.java:9)

Comment: @Anand: you have to pass in the parameters as you would pass them to JMeter on the command line, so at minimum -t before the test file, and probably also -n to show no GUI. Look at the documentation for more. And of course you have to set the appropriate class path to include the JMeter JARs when you start your Java program.

Answer (score 1):

It's quite simple:

```
jmeter -t test.jmx
```