# Running Jmeter testplan in non GUI mode

Tags: java, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have created some test plans in Jmeter. Now I need to run them trough command line or java API.

Can anyone please suggest any links or examples on from CLI/JAVA API how to:

1. Start jmeter
2. Load the *.jmx [testplan] plan
3. Specify number of threads
4. Start the test
5. Redirect the output result xml to result directory.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In addition to previous comment on [how to run JMeter in non-GUI mode](http://blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode), number of threads can be passed as JMeter property as follows:

In Thread Group set "Number of Threads" to be  `${__property(users,,)}`

and set it as

```
jmeter -Jusers=50 -n -t Test_Plan.jmx -l results_folder\log.jtl
```

See [Apache JMeter Properties Customization](http://blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) Guide for more details.

In regards to running JMeter test from Java code refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19147235/how-to-create-and-run-apache-jmeter-test-scripts-from-a-java-program) thread.

For running JMeter scripts from Apache Ant there is [JMeter Ant Task](http://www.programmerplanet.org/projects/jmeter-ant-task/)

For running JMeter by Maven there is a [JMeter Maven plugin](http://wiki.apache.org/jmeter/JMeterMavenPlugin)

There is also [Jenkins plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/JMeter+Plugin) if you want to integrate it with Jenkins/Hudson

Comment: I am getting the below error on running trough CLI

C:\Users\xxx>jmeter -n -t C:\apache-jmeter2.11\bin\examples\abstract.jmx
-l C:\apache-jmeter-2.11\bin\examples\results\log.jtl

Error in NonGUIDriver java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: can you post the full stacktrace? And as a workaround it worth trying running jmeter from `c:\apache-jmeter211\bin` folder instead of c:\Users\xxx.

Answer (score 1):

***Now i need to run them trough command line or java API***

For running a jmeter test plan through CLI, you want a couple flags --

```
jmeter -n -t Test_Plan.jmx -l log.jtl
```

`-n` - Non gui mode

`-t` location of the test plan

`-l` log file to output

***Specify number of threads***

This is actually built into the test plan - you would want to edit the .jmx test plan to change the number of threads.