# In Jmeter how to use response json data as next request parameter

Tags: json, jmeter

I am using `Jmeter` to test my rest services. One rest call returns list of employees in JSON format. I need to parse this response and send it as parameter in next rest call to get employee details.

Is there any way to do so from `JMeter` tool?

Comment: Read about http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use JSON response from server to send POST request with parameters from JSON (jmeter)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23246321/how-to-use-json-response-from-server-to-send-post-request-with-parameters-from-j)

Comment: Basically you use some kind of postprocessor (in your case a json extractor sounds appropriate), then optionally a beanshell postprocessor to take that list of variables and convert them to more familiar variable names.  You can then add them to the next request by variable name or via a beanshell preprocessor to loop through them using sampler.addArgument.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes. It can be done in many ways. Please check this link below.

http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2014/06/12/parsing-json-responses-with-jmeter/