# How to Run a Jmeter script within Java code?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, jmeter

I'm unable to run the JMeter Java file with the below setup. Can anyone please help me and tell me what is wrong. I am using Eclipse with Maven integration.

Referring the post: [How to create and run Apache JMeter Test Scripts from a Java program?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19147235/3755692)

**Java code:**

```
package com.blazemeter.demo;

import org.apache.jmeter.control.LoopController;
import org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine;
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSampler;
import org.apache.jmeter.testelement.TestPlan;
import org.apache.jmeter.threads.SetupThreadGroup;
import org.apache.jmeter.util.JMeterUtils;
import org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree;

public class JMeterFromScratch {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        // Engine
        StandardJMeterEngine jm = new StandardJMeterEngine();
        // jmeter.properties
        JMeterUtils.loadJMeterProperties("C:/Users/sthomas/jmeter.properties");
        HashTree hashTree = new HashTree();     

        // HTTP Sampler
        HTTPSampler httpSampler = new HTTPSampler();
        httpSampler.setDomain("www.google.com");
        httpSampler.setPort(80);
        httpSampler.setPath("/");
        httpSampler.setMethod("GET");

        // Loop Controller
        LoopController loopCtrl = new LoopController();
        ((LoopController)loopCtrl).setLoops(1);
        ((LoopController)loopCtrl).addTestElement(httpSampler);
        ((LoopController)loopCtrl).setFirst(true);
        ((LoopController)loopCtrl).initialize();
        // Thread Group
        SetupThreadGroup threadGroup = new SetupThreadGroup();
        threadGroup.setNumThreads(1);
        threadGroup.setRampUp(1);
        threadGroup.setSamplerController((LoopController)loopCtrl);

        // Test plan
        TestPlan testPlan = new TestPlan("MY TEST PLAN");

        hashTree.add("testPlan", testPlan);
        hashTree.add("loopCtrl", loopCtrl);
        hashTree.add("threadGroup", threadGroup);
        hashTree.add("httpSampler", httpSampler);       

        jm.configure(hashTree);

        jm.run();
    }
}
```

---

**Jmeter.properties file**

```
log_level.jmeter=DEBUG
log_level.jmeter.junit=DEBUG
log_level.jmeter.control=DEBUG
log_level.jmeter.testbeans=DEBUG
log_level.jmeter.engine=DEBUG
log_level.jmeter.threads=DEBUG
log_level.jmeter.gui=WARN
log_level.jmeter.testelement=DEBUG
log_level.jmeter.util=DEBUG
log_level.jmeter.util.classfinder=DEBUG
log_level.jmeter.test=DEBUG
log_level.jmeter.protocol.http=DEBUG
# For CookieManager, AuthManager etc:
log_level.jmeter.protocol.http.control=DEBUG
log_level.jmeter.protocol.ftp=WARN
log_level.jmeter.protocol.jdbc=DEBUG
log_level.jmeter.protocol.java=WARN
log_level.jmeter.testelements.property=DEBUG
log_level.jorphan=DEBUG
jmeterengine.startlistenerslater=false
log_file=jmeter-debug.log
```

---

**Debug Log:**

```
2014-11-03 16:29:36.905 [jmeter.e] (): Listeners will be started after enabling running version
INFO    2014-11-03 16:29:36.967 [jmeter.e] (): To revert to the earlier behaviour, define jmeterengine.startlistenerslater=false
INFO    2014-11-03 16:29:36.983 [jmeter.p] (): No response parsers defined: text/html only will be scanned for embedded resources
INFO    2014-11-03 16:29:36.991 [jmeter.p] (): Maximum connection retries = 10
INFO    2014-11-03 16:29:37.001 [jmeter.e] (): Running the test!
INFO    2014-11-03 16:29:37.009 [jmeter.s] (): List of sample_variables: []
INFO    2014-11-03 16:29:37.009 [jmeter.s] (): List of sample_variables: []
DEBUG   2014-11-03 16:29:37.016 [jorphan.] (): searchPathsOrJars : [null/lib/ext]
DEBUG   2014-11-03 16:29:37.016 [jorphan.] (): superclass : [interface org.apache.jmeter.functions.Function]
DEBUG   2014-11-03 16:29:37.016 [jorphan.] (): innerClasses : true annotations: false
DEBUG   2014-11-03 16:29:37.016 [jorphan.] (): contains: null notContains: null
DEBUG   2014-11-03 16:29:37.017 [jorphan.] (): Classpath = C:\Users\sthomas\workspace\JmeterProj\target\classes;C:\Users\sthomas\.m2\repository\org\apache\jmeter\ApacheJMeter_core\2.11\ApacheJMeter_core-2.11.jar;C:\Users\sthomas\.m2\repository\avalon-framework\avalon-framework\4.1.4\avalon-framework-4.1.4.jar;C:\Users\sthomas\.m2\repository\org\apache\jmeter\ApacheJMeter_http\2.11\ApacheJMeter_http-2.11.jar;C:\Users\sthomas\.m2\repository\commons-logging\commons-logging\1.2\commons-logging-1.2.jar;C:\Users\sthomas\.m2\repository\logkit\logkit\2.0\logkit-2.0.jar;C:\Users\sthomas\.m2\repository\oro\oro\2.0.8\oro-2.0.8.jar;C:\Users\sthomas\.m2\repository\commons-io\commons-io\2.4\commons-io-2.4.jar;C:\Users\sthomas\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-lang3\3.3.2\commons-lang3-3.3.2.jar;C:\Users\sthomas\.m2\repository\com\thoughtworks\xstream\xstream\1.4.7\xstream-1.4.7.jar;C:\Users\sthomas\.m2\repository\org\apache\jmeter\jorphan\2.11\jorphan-2.11.jar;C:\Users\sthomas\.m2\repository\bsf\bsf\2.4.0\bsf-2.4.0.jar;C:\Users\sthomas\.m2\repository\org\beanshell\bsh\2.0b5\bsh-2.0b5.jar;C:\Users\sthomas\.m2\repository\org\bouncycastle\bcmail-jdk15on\1.49\bcmail-jdk15on-1.49.jar;C:\Users\sthomas\.m2\repository\org\bouncycastle\bcprov-jdk15on\1.49\bcprov-jdk15on-1.49.jar;C:\Users\sthomas\.m2\repository\org\bouncycastle\bcpkix-jdk15on\1.49\bcpkix-jdk15on-1.49.jar;C:\Users\sthomas\.m2\repository\commons-codec\commons-codec\1.8\commons-codec-1.8.jar;C:\Users\sthomas\.m2\repository\commons-collections\commons-collections\3.2.1\commons-collections-3.2.1.jar;C:\Users\sthomas\.m2\repository\commons-httpclient\commons-httpclient\3.1\commons-httpclient-3.1.jar;C:\Users\sthomas\.m2\repository\commons-jexl\commons-jexl\1.1\commons-jexl-1.1.jar;C:\Users\sthomas\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-jexl\2.1.1\commons-jexl-2.1.1.jar;C:\Users\sthomas\.m2\repository\commons-net\commons-net\3.3\commons-net-3.3.jar;C:\Users\sthomas\.m2\repository\excalibur-datasource\excalibur-datasource\1.1.1\excalibur-datasource-1.1.1.jar;C:\Users\sthomas\.m2\repository\excalibur-instrument\excalibur-instrument\1.0\excalibur-instrument-1.0.jar;C:\Users\sthomas\.m2\repository\excalibur-logger\excalibur-logger\1.1\excalibur-logger-1.1.jar;C:\Users\sthomas\.m2\repository\excalibur-pool\excalibur-pool\1.2\excalibur-pool-1.2.jar;C:\Users\sthomas\.m2\repository\org\htmlparser\htmllexer\2.1\htmllexer-2.1.jar;C:\Users\sthomas\.m2\repository\org\htmlparser\htmlparser\2.1\htmlparser-2.1.jar;C:\Users\sthomas\.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpclient\4.2.6\httpclient-4.2.6.jar;C:\Users\sthomas\.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpmime\4.2.6\httpmime-4.2.6.jar;C:\Users\sthomas\.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpcore\4.2.5\httpcore-4.2.5.jar;C:\Users\sthomas\.m2\repository\jcharts\jcharts\0.7.5\jcharts-0.7.5.jar;C:\Users\sthomas\.m2\repository\org\jdom\jdom\1.1.3\jdom-1.1.3.jar;C:\Users\sthomas\.m2\repository\org\mozilla\rhino\1.7R4\rhino-1.7R4.jar;C:\Users\sthomas\.m2\repository\junit\junit\4.11\junit-4.11.jar;C:\Users\sthomas\.m2\repository\org\hamcrest\hamcrest-core\1.3\hamcrest-core-1.3.jar;C:\Users\sthomas\.m2\repository\soap\soap\2.3.1\soap-2.3.1.jar;C:\Users\sthomas\.m2\repository\net\sf\jtidy\jtidy\r938\jtidy-r938.jar;C:\Users\sthomas\.m2\repository\org\apache\tika\tika-core\1.4\tika-core-1.4.jar;C:\Users\sthomas\.m2\repository\org\apache\tika\tika-parsers\1.4\tika-parsers-1.4.jar;C:\Users\sthomas\.m2\repository\org\gagravarr\vorbis-java-tika\0.1\vorbis-java-tika-0.1.jar;C:\Users\sthomas\.m2\repository\org\gagravarr\vorbis-java-core\0.1\vorbis-java-core-0.1-tests.jar;C:\Users\sthomas\.m2\repository\edu\ucar\netcdf\4.2-min\netcdf-4.2-min.jar;C:\Users\sthomas\.m2\repository\org\apache\james\apache-mime4j-core\0.7.2\apache-mime4j-core-0.7.2.jar;C:\Users\sthomas\.m2\repository\org\apache\james\apache-mime4j-dom\0.7.2\apache-mime4j-dom-0.7.2.jar;C:\Users\sthomas\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-compress\1.5\commons-compress-1.5.jar;C:\Users\sthomas\.m2\repository\org\tukaani\xz\1.2\xz-1.2.jar;C:\Users\sthomas\.m2\repository\org\apache\pdfbox\pdfbox\1.8.1\pdfbox-1.8.1.jar;C:\Users\sthomas\.m2\repository\org\apache\pdfbox\fontbox\1.8.1\fontbox-1.8.1.jar;C:\Users\sthomas\.m2\repository\org\apache\pdfbox\jempbox\1.8.1\jempbox-1.8.1.jar;C:\Users\sthomas\.m2\repository\org\bouncycastle\bcmail-jdk15\1.45\bcmail-jdk15-1.45.jar;C:\Users\sthomas\.m2\repository\org\bouncycastle\bcprov-jdk15\1.45\bcprov-jdk15-1.45.jar;C:\Users\sthomas\.m2\repository\org\apache\poi\poi\3.9\poi-3.9.jar;C:\Users\sthomas\.m2\repository\org\apache\poi\poi-scratchpad\3.9\poi-scratchpad-3.9.jar;C:\Users\sthomas\.m2\repository\org\apache\poi\poi-ooxml\3.9\poi-ooxml-3.9.jar;C:\Users\sthomas\.m2\repository\org\apache\poi\poi-ooxml-schemas\3.9\poi-ooxml-schemas-3.9.jar;C:\Users\sthomas\.m2\repository\org\apache\xmlbeans\xmlbeans\2.3.0\xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar;C:\Users\sthomas\.m2\repository\dom4j\dom4j\1.6.1\dom4j-1.6.1.jar;C:\Users\sthomas\.m2\repository\org\apache\geronimo\specs\geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec\1.0.1\geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec-1.0.1.jar;C:\Users\sthomas\.m2\repository\org\ccil\cowan\tagsoup\tagsoup\1.2.1\tagsoup-1.2.1.jar;C:\Users\sthomas\.m2\repository\org\ow2\asm\asm-debug-all\4.1\asm-debug-all-4.1.jar;C:\Users\sthomas\.m2\repository\com\googlecode\mp4parser\isoparser\1.0-RC-1\isoparser-1.0-RC-1.jar;C:\Users\sthomas\.m2\repository\org\aspectj\aspectjrt\1.6.11\aspectjrt-1.6.11.jar;C:\Users\sthomas\.m2\repository\com\drewnoakes\metadata-extractor\2.6.2\metadata-extractor-2.6.2.jar;C:\Users\sthomas\.m2\repository\com\adobe\xmp\xmpcore\5.1.2\xmpcore-5.1.2.jar;C:\Users\sthomas\.m2\repository\de\l3s\boilerpipe\boilerpipe\1.1.0\boilerpipe-1.1.0.jar;C:\Users\sthomas\.m2\repository\rome\rome\0.9\rome-0.9.jar;C:\Users\sthomas\.m2\repository\jdom\jdom\1.0\jdom-1.0.jar;C:\Users\sthomas\.m2\repository\org\gagravarr\vorbis-java-core\0.1\vorbis-java-core-0.1.jar;C:\Users\sthomas\.m2\repository\com\googlecode\juniversalchardet\juniversalchardet\1.0.3\juniversalchardet-1.0.3.jar;C:\Users\sthomas\.m2\repository\xmlpull\xmlpull\1.1.3.1\xmlpull-1.1.3.1.jar;C:\Users\sthomas\.m2\repository\xpp3\xpp3_min\1.1.4c\xpp3_min-1.1.4c.jar;C:\Users\sthomas\.m2\repository\xalan\xalan\2.7.1\xalan-2.7.1.jar;C:\Users\sthomas\.m2\repository\xalan\serializer\2.7.1\serializer-2.7.1.jar;C:\Users\sthomas\.m2\repository\xerces\xercesImpl\2.9.1\xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar;C:\Users\sthomas\.m2\repository\xml-apis\xml-apis\1.3.04\xml-apis-1.3.04.jar;C:\Users\sthomas\.m2\repository\org\apache\xmlgraphics\xmlgraphics-commons\1.5\xmlgraphics-commons-1.5.jar;C:\Users\sthomas\.m2\repository\javax\mail\mail\1.5.0-b01\mail-1.5.0-b01.jar;C:\Users\sthomas\.m2\repository\javax\activation\activation\1.1\activation-1.1.jar;C:\Users\sthomas\.m2\repository\org\apache\geronimo\specs\geronimo-jms_1.1_spec\1.1.1\geronimo-jms_1.1_spec-1.1.1.jar;C:\Users\sthomas\.m2\repository\org\jsoup\jsoup\1.7.3\jsoup-1.7.3.jar;C:\Users\sthomas\.m2\repository\org\jodd\jodd-core\3.4.10\jodd-core-3.4.10.jar;C:\Users\sthomas\.m2\repository\org\jodd\jodd-lagarto\3.4.10\jodd-lagarto-3.4.10.jar;C:\Users\sthomas\.m2\repository\org\mongodb\mongo-java-driver\2.11.3\mongo-java-driver-2.11.3.jar;C:\Users\sthomas\.m2\repository\com\fifesoft\rsyntaxtextarea\2.5.1\rsyntaxtextarea-2.5.1.jar;C:\Users\sthomas\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.5\slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar;C:\Users\sthomas\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-nop\1.7.5\slf4j-nop-1.7.5.jar
DEBUG   2014-11-03 16:29:37.017 [jorphan.] (): strPathsOrJars[0] : null/lib/ext
DEBUG   2014-11-03 16:29:37.018 [jorphan.] (): Did not find: C:/Users/sthomas/workspace/JmeterProj/target/classes
DEBUG   2014-11-03 16:29:37.018 [jorphan.] (): Did not find: C:/Users/sthomas/.m2/repository/org/apache/jmeter/ApacheJMeter_core/2.11/ApacheJMeter_core-2.11.jar
DEBUG   2014-11-03 16:29:37.018 [jorphan.] (): Did not find: C:/Users/sthomas/.m2/repository/avalon-framework/avalon-framework/4.1.4/avalon-framework-4.1.4.jar
DEBUG   2014-11-03 16:29:37.018 [jorphan.] (): Did not find: C:/Users/sthomas/.m2/repository/org/apache/jmeter/ApacheJMeter_http/2.11/ApacheJMeter_http-2.11.jar
DEBUG   2014-11-03 16:29:37.018 [jorphan.] (): Did not find: C:/Users/sthomas/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.2/commons-logging-1.2.jar
DEBUG   2014-11-03 16:29:37.018 [jorphan.] (): Did not find: C:/Users/sthomas/.m2/repository/logkit/logkit/2.0/logkit-2.0.jar
DEBUG   2014-11-03 16:29:37.018 [jorphan.] (): Did not find: C:/Users/sthomas/.m2/repository/oro/oro/2.0.8/oro-2.0.8.jar
DEBUG   2014-11-03 16:29:37.018 [jorphan.] (): Did not find: C:/Users/sthomas/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/2.4/commons-io-2.4.jar
DEBUG   2014-11-03 16:29:37.018 [jorphan.] (): Did not find: C:/Users/sthomas/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.3.2/commons-lang3-3.3.2.jar
DEBUG   2014-11-03 16:29:37.018 [jorphan.] (): Did not find: C:/Users/sthomas/.m2/repository/com/thoughtworks/xstream/xstream/1.4.7/xstream-1.4.7.jar
DEBUG   2014-11-03 16:29:37.018 [jorphan.] (): Did not find: C:/Users/sthomas/.m2/repository/org/apache/jmeter/jorphan/2.11/jorphan-2.11.jar
DEBUG   2014-11-03 16:29:37.018 [jorphan.] (): Did not find: C:/Users/sthomas/.m2/repository/bsf/bsf/2.4.0/bsf-2.4.0.jar
DEBUG   2014-11-03 16:29:37.018 [jorphan.] (): Did not find: C:/Users/sthomas/.m2/repository/org/beanshell/bsh/2.0b5/bsh-2.0b5.jar
DEBUG   2014-11-03 16:29:37.018 [jorphan.] (): Did not find: C:/Users/sthomas/.m2/repository/org/bouncycastle/bcmail-jdk15on/1.49/bcmail-jdk15on-1.49.jar
DEBUG   2014-11-03 16:29:37.019 [jorphan.] (): Did not find: C:/Users/sthomas/.m2/repository/org/bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on/1.49/bcprov-jdk15on-1.49.jar
DEBUG   2014-11-03 16:29:37.019 [jorphan.] (): Did not find: C:/Users/sthomas/.m2/repository/org/bouncycastle/bcpkix-jdk15on/1.49/bcpkix-jdk15on-1.49.jar
DEBUG   2014-11-03 16:29:37.019 [jorphan.] (): Did not find: C:/Users/sthomas/.m2/repository/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.8/commons-codec-1.8.jar
DEBUG   2014-11-03 16:29:37.019 [jorphan.] (): Did not find: C:/Users/sthomas/.m2/repository/commons-collections/commons-collections/3.2.1/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
DEBUG   2014-11-03 16:29:37.019 [jorphan.] (): Did not find: C:/Users/sthomas/.m2/repository/commons-httpclient/commons-httpclient/3.1/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar
DEBUG   2014-11-03 16:29:37.019 [jorphan.] (): Did not find: C:/Users/sthomas/.m2/repository/commons-jexl/commons-jexl/1.1/commons-jexl-1.1.jar
DEBUG   2014-11-03 16:29:37.019 [jorphan.] (): Did not find: C:/Users/sthomas/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-jexl/2.1.1/commons-jexl-2.1.1.jar
DEBUG   2014-11-03 16:29:37.019 [jorphan.] (): Did not find: C:/Users/sthomas/.m2/repository/commons-net/commons-net/3.3/commons-net-3.3.jar
DEBUG   2014-11-03 16:29:37.019 [jorphan.] (): Did not find: C:/Users/sthomas/.m2/repository/excalibur-datasource/excalibur-datasource/1.1.1/excalibur-datasource-1.1.1.jar
DEBUG   2014-11-03 16:29:37.019 [jorphan.] (): Did not find: C:/Users/sthomas/.m2/repository/excalibur-instrument/excalibur-instrument/1.0/excalibur-instrument-1.0.jar
DEBUG   2014-11-03 16:29:37.019 [jorphan.] (): Did not find: C:/Users/sthomas/.m2/repository/excalibur-logger/excalibur-logger/1.1/excalibur-logger-1.1.jar
DEBUG   2014-11-03 16:29:37.019 [jorphan.] (): Did not find: C:/Users/sthomas/.m2/repository/excalibur-pool/excalibur-pool/1.2/excalibur-pool-1.2.jar
DEBUG   2014-11-03 16:29:37.019 [jorphan.] (): Did not find: C:/Users/sthomas/.m2/repository/org/htmlparser/htmllexer/2.1/htmllexer-2.1.jar
DEBUG   2014-11-03 16:29:37.019 [jorphan.] (): Did not find: C:/Users/sthomas/.m2/repository/org/htmlparser/htmlparser/2.1/htmlparser-2.1.jar
DEBUG   2014-11-03 16:29:37.019 [jorphan.] (): Did not find: C:/Users/sthomas/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.2.6/httpclient-4.2.6.jar
DEBUG   2014-11-03 16:29:37.020 [jorphan.] (): Did not find: C:/Users/sthomas/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpmime/4.2.6/httpmime-4.2.6.jar
DEBUG   2014-11-03 16:29:37.020 [jorphan.] (): Did not find: C:/Users/sthomas/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.2.5/httpcore-4.2.5.jar
DEBUG   2014-11-03 16:29:37.020 [jorphan.] (): Did not find: C:/Users/sthomas/.m2/repository/jcharts/jcharts/0.7.5/jcharts-0.7.5.jar
DEBUG   2014-11-03 16:29:37.020 [jorphan.] (): Did not find: C:/Users/sthomas/.m2/repository/org/jdom/jdom/1.1.3/jdom-1.1.3.jar
DEBUG   2014-11-03 16:29:37.020 [jorphan.] (): Did not find: C:/Users/sthomas/.m2/repository/org/mozilla/rhino/1.7R4/rhino-1.7R4.jar
DEBUG   2014-11-03 16:29:37.020 [jorphan.] (): Did not find: C:/Users/sthomas/.m2/repository/junit/junit/4.11/junit-4.11.jar
DEBUG   2014-11-03 16:29:37.020 [jorphan.] (): Did not find: C:/Users/sthomas/.m2/repository/org/hamcrest/hamcrest-core/1.3/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar
DEBUG   2014-11-03 16:29:37.020 [jorphan.] (): Did not find: C:/Users/sthomas/.m2/repository/soap/soap/2.3.1/soap-2.3.1.jar
DEBUG   2014-11-03 16:29:37.020 [jorphan.] (): Did not find: C:/Users/sthomas/.m2/repository/net/sf/jtidy/jtidy/r938/jtidy-r938.jar
DEBUG   2014-11-03 16:29:37.020 [jorphan.] (): Did not find: C:/Users/sthomas/.m2/repository/org/apache/tika/tika-core/1.4/tika-core-1.4.jar
DEBUG   2014-11-03 16:29:37.020 [jorphan.] (): Did not find: C:/Users/sthomas/.m2/repository/org/apache/tika/tika-parsers/1.4/tika-parsers-1.4.jar
DEBUG   2014-11-03 16:29:37.020 [jorphan.] (): Did not find: C:/Users/sthomas/.m2/repository/org/gagravarr/vorbis-java-tika/0.1/vorbis-java-tika-0.1.jar
DEBUG   2014-11-03 16:29:37.020 [jorphan.] (): Did not find: C:/Users/sthomas/.m2/repository/org/gagravarr/vorbis-java-core/0.1/vorbis-java-core-0.1-tests.jar
DEBUG   2014-11-03 16:29:37.020 [jorphan.] (): Did not find: C:/Users/sthomas/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/netcdf/4.2-min/netcdf-4.2-min.jar
DEBUG   2014-11-03 16:29:37.020 [jorphan.] (): Did not find: C:/Users/sthomas/.m2/repository/org/apache/james/apache-mime4j-core/0.7.2/apache-mime4j-core-0.7.2.jar
DEBUG   2014-11-03 16:29:37.020 [jorphan.] (): Did not find: C:/Users/sthomas/.m2/repository/org/apache/james/apache-mime4j-dom/0.7.2/apache-mime4j-dom-0.7.2.jar
DEBUG   2014-11-03 16:29:37.021 [jorphan.] (): Did not find: C:/Users/sthomas/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-compress/1.5/commons-compress-1.5.jar
DEBUG   2014-11-03 16:29:37.021 [jorphan.] (): Did not find: C:/Users/sthomas/.m2/repository/org/tukaani/xz/1.2/xz-1.2.jar
DEBUG   2014-11-03 16:29:37.021 [jorphan.] (): Did not find: C:/Users/sthomas/.m2/repository/org/apache/pdfbox/pdfbox/1.8.1/pdfbox-1.8.1.jar
DEBUG   2014-11-03 16:29:37.021 [jorphan.] (): Did not find: C:/Users/sthomas/.m2/repository/org/apache/pdfbox/fontbox/1.8.1/fontbox-1.8.1.jar
DEBUG   2014-11-03 16:29:37.021 [jorphan.] (): Did not find: C:/Users/sthomas/.m2/repository/org/apache/pdfbox/jempbox/1.8.1/jempbox-1.8.1.jar
DEBUG   2014-11-03 16:29:37.021 [jorphan.] (): Did not find: C:/Users/sthomas/.m2/repository/org/bouncycastle/bcmail-jdk15/1.45/bcmail-jdk15-1.45.jar
DEBUG   2014-11-03 16:29:37.021 [jorphan.] (): Did not find: C:/Users/sthomas/.m2/repository/org/bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15/1.45/bcprov-jdk15-1.45.jar
DEBUG   2014-11-03 16:29:37.021 [jorphan.] (): Did not find: C:/Users/sthomas/.m2/repository/org/apache/poi/poi/3.9/poi-3.9.jar
DEBUG   2014-11-03 16:29:37.021 [jorphan.] (): Did not find: C:/Users/sthomas/.m2/repository/org/apache/poi/poi-scratchpad/3.9/poi-scratchpad-3.9.jar
DEBUG   2014-11-03 16:29:37.021 [jorphan.] (): Did not find: C:/Users/sthomas/.m2/repository/org/apache/poi/poi-ooxml/3.9/poi-ooxml-3.9.jar
DEBUG   2014-11-03 16:29:37.021 [jorphan.] (): Did not find: C:/Users/sthomas/.m2/repository/org/apache/poi/poi-ooxml-schemas/3.9/poi-ooxml-schemas-3.9.jar
DEBUG   2014-11-03 16:29:37.021 [jorphan.] (): Did not find: C:/Users/sthomas/.m2/repository/org/apache/xmlbeans/xmlbeans/2.3.0/xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar
DEBUG   2014-11-03 16:29:37.021 [jorphan.] (): Did not find: C:/Users/sthomas/.m2/repository/dom4j/dom4j/1.6.1/dom4j-1.6.1.jar
DEBUG   2014-11-03 16:29:37.021 [jorphan.] (): Did not find: C:/Users/sthomas/.m2/repository/org/apache/geronimo/specs/geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec/1.0.1/geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec-1.0.1.jar
DEBUG   2014-11-03 16:29:37.022 [jorphan.] (): Did not find: C:/Users/sthomas/.m2/repository/org/ccil/cowan/tagsoup/tagsoup/1.2.1/tagsoup-1.2.1.jar
DEBUG   2014-11-03 16:29:37.022 [jorphan.] (): Did not find: C:/Users/sthomas/.m2/repository/org/ow2/asm/asm-debug-all/4.1/asm-debug-all-4.1.jar
DEBUG   2014-11-03 16:29:37.022 [jorphan.] (): Did not find: C:/Users/sthomas/.m2/repository/com/googlecode/mp4parser/isoparser/1.0-RC-1/isoparser-1.0-RC-1.jar
DEBUG   2014-11-03 16:29:37.022 [jorphan.] (): Did not find: C:/Users/sthomas/.m2/repository/org/aspectj/aspectjrt/1.6.11/aspectjrt-1.6.11.jar
DEBUG   2014-11-03 16:29:37.022 [jorphan.] (): Did not find: C:/Users/sthomas/.m2/repository/com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor/2.6.2/metadata-extractor-2.6.2.jar
DEBUG   2014-11-03 16:29:37.022 [jorphan.] (): Did not find: C:/Users/sthomas/.m2/repository/com/adobe/xmp/xmpcore/5.1.2/xmpcore-5.1.2.jar
DEBUG   2014-11-03 16:29:37.022 [jorphan.] (): Did not find: C:/Users/sthomas/.m2/repository/de/l3s/boilerpipe/boilerpipe/1.1.0/boilerpipe-1.1.0.jar
DEBUG   2014-11-03 16:29:37.022 [jorphan.] (): Did not find: C:/Users/sthomas/.m2/repository/rome/rome/0.9/rome-0.9.jar
DEBUG   2014-11-03 16:29:37.022 [jorphan.] (): Did not find: C:/Users/sthomas/.m2/repository/jdom/jdom/1.0/jdom-1.0.jar
DEBUG   2014-11-03 16:29:37.022 [jorphan.] (): Did not find: C:/Users/sthomas/.m2/repository/org/gagravarr/vorbis-java-core/0.1/vorbis-java-core-0.1.jar
DEBUG   2014-11-03 16:29:37.022 [jorphan.] (): Did not find: C:/Users/sthomas/.m2/repository/com/googlecode/juniversalchardet/juniversalchardet/1.0.3/juniversalchardet-1.0.3.jar
DEBUG   2014-11-03 16:29:37.022 [jorphan.] (): Did not find: C:/Users/sthomas/.m2/repository/xmlpull/xmlpull/1.1.3.1/xmlpull-1.1.3.1.jar
DEBUG   2014-11-03 16:29:37.022 [jorphan.] (): Did not find: C:/Users/sthomas/.m2/repository/xpp3/xpp3_min/1.1.4c/xpp3_min-1.1.4c.jar
DEBUG   2014-11-03 16:29:37.022 [jorphan.] (): Did not find: C:/Users/sthomas/.m2/repository/xalan/xalan/2.7.1/xalan-2.7.1.jar
DEBUG   2014-11-03 16:29:37.022 [jorphan.] (): Did not find: C:/Users/sthomas/.m2/repository/xalan/serializer/2.7.1/serializer-2.7.1.jar
DEBUG   2014-11-03 16:29:37.023 [jorphan.] (): Did not find: C:/Users/sthomas/.m2/repository/xerces/xercesImpl/2.9.1/xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar
DEBUG   2014-11-03 16:29:37.023 [jorphan.] (): Did not find: C:/Users/sthomas/.m2/repository/xml-apis/xml-apis/1.3.04/xml-apis-1.3.04.jar
DEBUG   2014-11-03 16:29:37.023 [jorphan.] (): Did not find: C:/Users/sthomas/.m2/repository/org/apache/xmlgraphics/xmlgraphics-commons/1.5/xmlgraphics-commons-1.5.jar
DEBUG   2014-11-03 16:29:37.023 [jorphan.] (): Did not find: C:/Users/sthomas/.m2/repository/javax/mail/mail/1.5.0-b01/mail-1.5.0-b01.jar
DEBUG   2014-11-03 16:29:37.023 [jorphan.] (): Did not find: C:/Users/sthomas/.m2/repository/javax/activation/activation/1.1/activation-1.1.jar
DEBUG   2014-11-03 16:29:37.023 [jorphan.] (): Did not find: C:/Users/sthomas/.m2/repository/org/apache/geronimo/specs/geronimo-jms_1.1_spec/1.1.1/geronimo-jms_1.1_spec-1.1.1.jar
DEBUG   2014-11-03 16:29:37.023 [jorphan.] (): Did not find: C:/Users/sthomas/.m2/repository/org/jsoup/jsoup/1.7.3/jsoup-1.7.3.jar
DEBUG   2014-11-03 16:29:37.023 [jorphan.] (): Did not find: C:/Users/sthomas/.m2/repository/org/jodd/jodd-core/3.4.10/jodd-core-3.4.10.jar
DEBUG   2014-11-03 16:29:37.023 [jorphan.] (): Did not find: C:/Users/sthomas/.m2/repository/org/jodd/jodd-lagarto/3.4.10/jodd-lagarto-3.4.10.jar
DEBUG   2014-11-03 16:29:37.023 [jorphan.] (): Did not find: C:/Users/sthomas/.m2/repository/org/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/2.11.3/mongo-java-driver-2.11.3.jar
DEBUG   2014-11-03 16:29:37.023 [jorphan.] (): Did not find: C:/Users/sthomas/.m2/repository/com/fifesoft/rsyntaxtextarea/2.5.1/rsyntaxtextarea-2.5.1.jar
DEBUG   2014-11-03 16:29:37.023 [jorphan.] (): Did not find: C:/Users/sthomas/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.5/slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar
DEBUG   2014-11-03 16:29:37.023 [jorphan.] (): Did not find: C:/Users/sthomas/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-nop/1.7.5/slf4j-nop-1.7.5.jar
DEBUG   2014-11-03 16:29:37.024 [jorphan.] (): listClasses.size()=0
WARN    2014-11-03 16:29:37.024 [jmeter.e] (): Did not find any functions
DEBUG   2014-11-03 16:29:37.026 [jmeter.e] (): About to replace in property of type: class org.apache.jmeter.testelement.property.IntegerProperty: 1
DEBUG   2014-11-03 16:29:37.026 [jmeter.e] (): Won't replace 1
DEBUG   2014-11-03 16:29:37.026 [jmeter.e] (): About to replace in property of type: class org.apache.jmeter.testelement.property.IntegerProperty: 1
DEBUG   2014-11-03 16:29:37.026 [jmeter.e] (): Won't replace 1
DEBUG   2014-11-03 16:29:37.026 [jmeter.e] (): About to replace in property of type: class org.apache.jmeter.testelement.property.TestElementProperty: org.apache.jmeter.control.LoopController@bdf5e5
DEBUG   2014-11-03 16:29:37.026 [jmeter.e] (): About to replace in property of type: class org.apache.jmeter.testelement.property.BooleanProperty: false
DEBUG   2014-11-03 16:29:37.026 [jmeter.e] (): Won't replace false
DEBUG   2014-11-03 16:29:37.026 [jmeter.e] (): About to replace in property of type: class org.apache.jmeter.testelement.property.IntegerProperty: 1
DEBUG   2014-11-03 16:29:37.026 [jmeter.e] (): Won't replace 1
DEBUG   2014-11-03 16:29:37.026 [jmeter.e] (): Replacement result: org.apache.jmeter.control.LoopController@bdf5e5
DEBUG   2014-11-03 16:29:37.027 [jmeter.e] (): About to replace in property of type: class org.apache.jmeter.testelement.property.TestElementProperty: 
DEBUG   2014-11-03 16:29:37.027 [jmeter.e] (): About to replace in property of type: class org.apache.jmeter.testelement.property.CollectionProperty: []
DEBUG   2014-11-03 16:29:37.027 [jmeter.e] (): Replacement result: []
DEBUG   2014-11-03 16:29:37.027 [jmeter.e] (): Replacement result: 
DEBUG   2014-11-03 16:29:37.027 [jmeter.e] (): About to replace in property of type: class org.apache.jmeter.testelement.property.StringProperty: www.google.com
DEBUG   2014-11-03 16:29:37.027 [jmeter.e] (): Replacement result: www.google.com
DEBUG   2014-11-03 16:29:37.027 [jmeter.e] (): About to replace in property of type: class org.apache.jmeter.testelement.property.IntegerProperty: 80
DEBUG   2014-11-03 16:29:37.027 [jmeter.e] (): Won't replace 80
DEBUG   2014-11-03 16:29:37.028 [jmeter.e] (): About to replace in property of type: class org.apache.jmeter.testelement.property.StringProperty: /
DEBUG   2014-11-03 16:29:37.028 [jmeter.e] (): Replacement result: /
DEBUG   2014-11-03 16:29:37.028 [jmeter.e] (): About to replace in property of type: class org.apache.jmeter.testelement.property.StringProperty: GET
DEBUG   2014-11-03 16:29:37.028 [jmeter.e] (): Replacement result: GET
DEBUG   2014-11-03 16:29:37.028 [jmeter.e] (): About to replace in property of type: class org.apache.jmeter.testelement.property.StringProperty: MY TEST PLAN
DEBUG   2014-11-03 16:29:37.028 [jmeter.e] (): Replacement result: MY TEST PLAN
DEBUG   2014-11-03 16:29:37.030 [jmeter.e] (): About to replace in property of type: class org.apache.jmeter.testelement.property.BooleanProperty: false
DEBUG   2014-11-03 16:29:37.030 [jmeter.e] (): Won't replace false
DEBUG   2014-11-03 16:29:37.030 [jmeter.e] (): About to replace in property of type: class org.apache.jmeter.testelement.property.IntegerProperty: 1
DEBUG   2014-11-03 16:29:37.030 [jmeter.e] (): Won't replace 1
INFO    2014-11-03 16:29:37.033 [jmeter.e] (): Starting setUp thread groups
INFO    2014-11-03 16:29:37.033 [jmeter.e] (): Starting setUp ThreadGroup: 1 : 
INFO    2014-11-03 16:29:37.033 [jmeter.e] (): Starting 1 threads for group .
INFO    2014-11-03 16:29:37.033 [jmeter.e] (): Thread will continue on error
INFO    2014-11-03 16:29:37.035 [jmeter.t] (): Starting thread group number 1 threads 1 ramp-up 1 perThread 1000.0 delayedStart=false
INFO    2014-11-03 16:29:37.040 [jmeter.t] (): jmeterthread.startearlier=true (see jmeter.properties)
INFO    2014-11-03 16:29:37.040 [jmeter.t] (): Running PostProcessors in forward order
INFO    2014-11-03 16:29:37.042 [jmeter.t] (): Started thread group number 1
INFO    2014-11-03 16:29:37.042 [jmeter.e] (): Waiting for all setup thread groups to exit
DEBUG   2014-11-03 16:29:37.043 [jmeter.t] (): Subtracting node, stack size = 1
INFO    2014-11-03 16:29:37.045 [jmeter.t] (): Thread started:  1-1
DEBUG   2014-11-03 16:29:37.055 [jmeter.c] (): Calling next on: org.apache.jmeter.control.LoopController
INFO    2014-11-03 16:29:37.055 [jmeter.t] (): Thread finished:  1-1
DEBUG   2014-11-03 16:29:37.055 [jmeter.t] (): Ending thread  1-1
INFO    2014-11-03 16:29:37.056 [jmeter.e] (): All Setup Threads have ended
INFO    2014-11-03 16:29:37.063 [jmeter.e] (): No enabled thread groups found
INFO    2014-11-03 16:29:37.063 [jmeter.e] (): Notifying test listeners of end of test
INFO    2014-11-03 16:29:37.064 [jmeter.s] (): Default base='C:\Users\sthomas\workspace\JmeterProj'
```

Comment: Holy giant wall of text Batman!

Comment: What are the permissions on your local .m2 repo? It is telling you it can't find those jars for some reason. What is in your pom.xml?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look into [5 Ways To Launch a JMeter Test without Using the JMeter GUI guide](http://blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui) guide in general and into sample Maven-based demo project at https://bitbucket.org/blazemeter/jmeter-from-code/ in particular, hopefully it clarifies everything.

Comment: I converted this example into a GitHub Gradle project:  https://github.com/djangofan/java-jmeter

Answer (score 1):

You might use [jmeter-java-dsl](https://abstracta.github.io/jmeter-java-dsl/) to ease this task. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63409109/3853437) is an example of it.

Answer (score 0):

If you use maven then navigate to your app working directory, open the cmd and try the command:

```
mvn dependency:purge-local-repository
```

It works for me. Hope this help.