# How to use Jmeter APIs to make load tests and generate CSV report file

Tags: java, jmeter

I want to code Java classes to make load testing using `jmeter` APIs. I have tried many things without a result and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19147235/how-to-create-and-run-apache-jmeter-test-scripts-from-a-java-program) don't work for me.

Comment: it is good provide the code snipped or exception your getting that will help  to understand/resolve the issue.

Comment: i want to start a JMeter test purely in Java i used what is shown here: http://blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui
but it does not work

Comment: here is the output:
WARN    2015-04-10 14:22:59.358 [jmeter.u] (): Unexpected value set for boolean property:'server.exitaftertest', defaulting to:false
WARN    2015-04-10 14:22:59.378 [jmeter.u] (): Unexpected value set for boolean property:'jmeterengine.startlistenerslater', defaulting to:true
INFO    2015-04-10 14:22:59.378 [jmeter.e] (): Listeners will be started after enabling running version

Comment: INFO    2015-04-10 14:22:59.378 [jmeter.e] (): To revert to the earlier behaviour, define jmeterengine.startlistenerslater=false
WARN    2015-04-10 14:22:59.378 [jmeter.u] (): Unexpected value set for boolean property:'jmeterengine.remote.system.exit', defaulting to:false
WARN    2015-04-10 14:22:59.378 [jmeter.u] (): Unexpected value set for boolean property:'jmeterengine.stopfail.system.exit', defaulting to:true
WARN    2015-04-10 14:22:59.378 [jmeter.u] (): Unexpected value set for boolean property:'jmeterengine.force.system.exit', defaulting to:false

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/thoughtworks/xstream/converters/ConversionException
 at org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine.run(StandardJMeterEngine.java:450)
 at jmeter.JMeterFromScratch.main(JMeterFromScratch.java:57)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 ... 2 more

Comment: look like its missing xstream-xx.jar file in classpath, check all required jar files are there in classpath.

Comment: Can you provide an example for using jmeter APIs for load test?

Comment: you are looking for load testing by jmter ui or by implementing jmter API?, there two approachs one u can write/record the jmter script by using the jmeter ui http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jmeter/, other by implementation by jmeter API.

Comment: yes i look for implementation by jmeter API 
could you help me to do it ?