# Jmeter API : writing a test plan in Java

Tags: java, jmeter

Is there a way to write a JMeter test plan as a Java project? Something like what you can do with Selenium browser testing?

So I want to be able to write in Java, then compile/ give the jar or java file to Jmeter to run as a test plan with optional slaves etc

Or any other language? A github or other public repository sample would be super.

Comment: JTP answer is probably what you need.

Comment: thanks should i del this then?

Comment: No no need to :)

Comment: It is see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19147235/how-to-create-and-run-apache-jmeter-test-scripts-from-a-java-program @dan this question is a duplicate