# jmeter - how to collect request, response and assertion results in a java program?

Tags: java, jmeter

I have followed the example given in [How to create and run Apache JMeter Test Scripts from a Java program?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19236643/3842201)
. The sample program runs the tree configured to the JMeter engine, I want to collect back the response, actual request, and assertion data. I have tried in a way below

```
SampleResult sampleResult = httpSamplerProxy.sample();
```

but this re-submits my request to API. Is there any way that I can get the results back without resubmission?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to "collect" this data amend your test configuration to store execution results into a .jtl results file like:

```
Summariser summer = null;
String summariserName = JMeterUtils.getPropDefault("summariser.name", "summary");
if (summariserName.length() > 0) {
    summer = new Summariser(summariserName);
}


// Store execution results into a .jtl file
String logFile = "/path/to/results.jtl"
ResultCollector logger = new ResultCollector(summer);
logger.setFilename(logFile);
hashTree.add(hashTree.getArray()[0], logger);
```

And then configure what you would like to store in its file using "normal" JMeter Properties, i.e. by adding the next lines to *user.properties* (located in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation:

```
jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.samplerData=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.requestHeaders=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.url=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.responseHeaders=true
```

References:

- [Results File Configuration](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config)
- [Useful JMeter Properties: Save Results. Save the World](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/useful-jmeter-properties-save-results-save-world)